# how to know controller call from which view

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I have two views and is call same controller and base on the view I need to load another view in controller

**For example:**

```
public function addname()
{
    if(viewname == 'assigned')
    {
        $this->load->view('ressigned');
    }
    if(viewname == 'unassigned')
    {
       $this->load->view('assign');
    }
}
```

Comment: your example isn't clear at all, pls specify exactly what you want.

Comment: Can't you just pass the viewname as a parameter? function addname($viewname)

Comment: I have two views which call the same controller using ajax request now how I know my controller call from witch view.

Comment: @jeroen yes, I can but I don't want to change in the view file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe have two different way.

1. using session. in this way. you must set any session that specifies the name of the view that you are in, and you can check it in the controller.
2. using URL. you can use a specific segment in URL that specifies the name of the view.
   after the call of controller get the segment and check it with the controller.